# Amazon ECS API spontaneous "(400) Bad Request" errors for ItemSearch()

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Starting at about 11 PM CST on 5/29/2017, I began receiving "(400) Bad Request" errors for all my `ItemSearch()` calls. I am using the C# API and have been doing so successfully for well over a year now with no problems. No code or configuration has changed on my end, and I have been able to reproduce the error both in production and development. My security credentials appear to still be valid according to the IAM Management Console, and I haven't received any communications from Amazon that would indicate that my account has been deactivated or anything of that nature.

This is what is returned for all of my calls:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at MyCode.com.amazonaws.ecs.AWSECommerceServicePortType.ItemSearch(ItemSearchRequest1 request)
```

Is anyone else experiencing this?

I did check [this very old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938591/amazon-api-itemsearch-returns-400-bad-request), but I don't believe it's relevant given how this sprung up out of nowhere and has been working perfectly for so long.